# Kdb AWS FIFO Queue interface

Tags: amazon-web-services, kdb

Is there a way to interface Kdb application with AWS FIFO Queue service i.e. publishing and reading data from AWS FIFO Queue.

Comment: What is KDB? Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [embedPy](https://code.kx.com/q/ml/embedpy/) to enable this easily.

For receiving you could call the wrapped python function on a timer using [.z.ts](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotz/#zts-timer).